# How to parse method signature from msg.data in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I need to parse method signature from msg.data in Solidity.
To understand what method are calling in msg.data.
So I need to understand that f.e user call transfer method in passed data
`sha3('transfer(address,uint256)'="0xa9059cbb"`

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```
if (msg.sig == bytes4(keccak256("transfer(address,uint256)"))) { ... }
```

or

```
interface MyInterface {
    function transfer(address,uint256) external;
}

...

if (msg.sig == MyInterface.transfer.selector) { ... }
```